# How to make the UIWebView render the standard version of a webpage instead of automatically being redirected to the mobile version?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The server in some ways redirecting all the request into its mobile version, in which it lacks information, I want to render the page in the standard version using the UIWebView. What would I have to do? I have tried to set the "User-Agent" of the NSURLMutableRequest to Safari but it does not work. Any ideas why?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];    
[mutableRequest setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1 Safari/533.4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `User-Agent`, not `User_Agent`